How to change rewrite slug for custom post type without conflicting w/ child pages of page with same slug
I have a custom post type for "Projects" and in the register_post_type() settings, I'm setting the rewrite parameter to array('slug' => 'our-projects'), so the permalink for a Project single view would render as our-projects/project-name. The issue I'm experiencing derives from the fact that I also have a page with the slug our-projects. The page itself renders fine at site.com/our-projects, however, if I set a page as the child of that page, resulting in the permalink /our-projects/child-page I end up getting a 404 error.
It appears WordPress is confused by that path and is likely expecting a Project post at that URL. Is there a way I can preserve the post type slug rewrite and still allow for the page w/ matching slug to have child pages at /our-projects/page-name? I see from existing threads such as this one that the wp_unique_post_slug hook may be of assistance here, but I'm not sure how to implement it in this instance. I'm also wondering if perhaps I should not set the rewrite option when declaring the post type, and instead filter/change the URL on the frontend in a different way? e.g. if a post has has /projects/ in the URL, change it to /our-projects/? Thanks for any assistance here!
